# iText + JavaScript : How to create advance search on table data

Tags: javascript, itext

I am trying to create a PDF document with search functionality using iText and javascript.

PDF documents contains :

- A textfield with a search button
- The information is available in a table
- Based on the input search string, the data in the table needs to be refreshed/filtered.

Really appreciate if any code examples can be provided for this. Thank you!
P.S : i am new to this.

Comment: By "table" do you mean a visual table in the PDF? Or some data structure in JavaScript in the PDF? Or a database table in some backend service you want to query?

Comment: The data is available in a visual table created using iText PdfPTable

Comment: Oh boy, you might want to look for a solution that's does not involve a pdf. You're asking for two technically possible things: data recognition/retrieval and text replacement in pdf, but these two things are generally hard unless the pdf in question follows certain patterns. Your question as is, is very broad, and also does not show what you've tried so far. I suggest doing a bit more research on the pdf format and  splitting the problem into more manageable pieces.

Comment: Hi Samuel,
Thanks for the comment. 
The functionality I am trying to implement was already achieved by one of our clients using Adobe Livecycle(unable to provide any samples because of security constraints) and my task is to automate this. 
By following some of the basic iText tutorials, I was able to create a interactive PDF(with some editable fields and button actions) and currently working on data filters on the table rows.
Hope this gives you the exact picture of what i'm trying to achieve. Thanks you!

Comment: *"The functionality I am trying to implement was already achieved by one of our clients using Adobe Livecycle"* - The Adobe Livecycle based solution most likely uses XFA forms, and the PDFs only serve as transport medium for these form definitions. XFA technology allows for much more dynamical behavior than PDFs without XFA, but the XFA specification is not standardized, XFA only works on very few PDF viewers (I only know the Adobe viewers), and support for XFA in PDFs is likely to be obsoleted in newer specification versions.

Comment: @mkl, Thanks for the suggestion. Observed that the Livecycle PDF is using XFA forms and I am currently working on understanding the concept of XFA forms.

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck,

*"I suggest doing a bit more research on the pdf format and splitting the problem into more manageable pieces."*
Following are the things I have tried(using javascript) from my end
1. Hiding the table rows.
2. Hiding all the cells on a row.
3. Deleting and recreating the table with new data.

But I was unable to find anything that could help me achieve this. Hope I'm thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I was thinking more along the lines of reading up on the pdf specification, and, since you're essentially trying to recreate an XFA form, probably that spec as well. I'll repeat mkl though, XFA is not widely supported and likely to not be supported in PDF 2.0